# ember-data, Reload model in rootState.error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got an ember model, it looks something like this (in coffee-script)

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  age:  DS.attr('number)

  becameError: ->
    #F it, i give up, reload
    @reload()
```

Only when I call `this.reload()` I get

```
Error: Attempted to handle event `reloadRecord` on <App.User:ember255:1> while in state rootState.error.
```

What's the correct way to reload the model from the server?

Answer (score 4):

if you want your model to reload from the server in the event that it enters an error state your model definition should look something like this.

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  age:  DS.attr('number)

  becameError: ->
    #F it, i give up, reload
    @get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.saved')
    @reload()
```

The key line being

```
@get('stateManager')transtionTo('loaded.saved')
```

Which seems kind of messy to get a model out of an error state. There might be a prettier way to do this once ember-data gets further along, so check the docs.

I should mention that if you want to try and recommit your changes, you can instead uses one of these

```
@get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.created.uncommitted') # New Models
@get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.updated')             # Updated models
```